# How to access NativeMethods.WS_VISIBLE

Tags: .net, wpf

I've found that there is a static class `NativeMethods` where many of the Win32 Constants are defined.

In my WPF program I need to create a `HwndSource` and therefore I'm in need of the `WS_CHILD` and `WS_VISIBLE` values.

Is there any way to use `NativeMethods.WS_VISIBLE` in my program without defining it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the boilerplate name for an **internal** class that contains pinvoke declarations.  It doesn't have to be called "NativeMethods" but FxCop complains if you don't name it that so it is the common choice.

The fact that it is *internal* stops you from using it in your own code.

This is not a problem, just declare your own internal NativeMethods class.  With only the declarations you actually use.  WS_VISIBLE and WS_CHILD are simple *const* declarations.  You'll find them declared in the WinUser.h file on your machine, stored in the Windows SDK directory.  But those are C declarations, a language that's been on the endangered species list lately, you can get the C# ones by simply by visiting the [pinvoke.net web site](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/Window%20styles.html).  It tends to have decent declarations that are already fit to copy/paste into your code, they are usually accurate.  Copy/pasting from the Reference Source or decompiler output tends to work as well.  Or use the PInvoke Interop Assistant.  No lack of sources :)

Comment: But that's exactly what I want to skip. The definitions are out there so why should I create another class, which hold the same things? What is the reason for MS to make this internal?

Comment: But that's exactly what you should not do.  Pinvoke is always an internal implementation detail.  Intentionally altering a pinvoke declaration is a very common technique, that should never be shared to other code.  Now you know why, it doesn't change at all what you need to do of course.